# div with 100% height, not able to scroll the content

Tags: html, css, devexpress, devextreme

I have tried to make my **content-div** (`height:100%`) scrollable, but it will not work. I have tried several tips from here, but I wasn't able to solve it. I'm using **devextreme** from DevExpress, but it shouldn't matter for the css.

I have created a sample of my problem on fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/phoniex/eop415ju/2/

The green header and the grey area on the left should be fixed. Only the white area should be scrollable. But the white-content-area isn't scrollable. I just get it scrollable if I change:

```
#layout_main_content {
  display: inline-block;
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

But now the content hasn't `height = 100%`

Comment: Check this one:
https://jsfiddle.net/gsfq1x7k/

Comment: Basically this is what I'm searching for, but with your example the scrollable-content isn't `height:100%` - the scrollable-area isn't down to bottom of the screen. Depending on the browser-windows there is an unused area below the scrollable-area. If you open the fiddle-layout to use tabs => only 50% of white-area is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#layout_main_content {
    display: block; //this was changed
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-bottom: 38px; //this was changed
}
```

Comment: It looks like that this just works in Google Chrome. Not in Firefox:

https://jsfiddle.net/phoniex/eop415ju/6/

Comment: Instead of height 100%, give a fixed height by using the calc function.
something like this ```height: calc(100vh - 105px);```

Comment: I have tried it: https://jsfiddle.net/phoniex/eop415ju/10/, `#layout_main_content {
    display: block;
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}`. But this also only works in Google Chrome, in Firefox (depending on the screensize) the calc-value has to be changed.